# switch and cannot find variable in scope

Tags: swift, xcode, switch-statement

Why should I create a variable outside of switch/case?
For example this code will have an error `Cannot find 'size' in scope`:

```
func sizeCheckNoVar(value: Int) -> String {
        switch value {
        case 0...2:
            let size = "small"
        case 3...5:
            let size = "medium"
        case 6...10:
            let size = "large"
        default:
            let size = "huge"
            
        }
        return size
    }
```

There is a default condition and AFIK all options are covered.

In the same time this code will be fine:

```
func sizeCheckVar(value: Int) -> String {
    var size: String
    switch value {
    case 0...2:
        size = "small"
    case 3...5:
        size = "medium"
    case 6...10:
        size = "large"
    default:
        size = "huge"
        
    }
    return size
}
```

PS I saw this question [Cannot find variable in scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64901490/cannot-find-variable-in-scope) , but I want to know **why** instead of **how to avoid**

Comment: Because when you create a variable  inside the case then the scope of the variable is within the case and you can’t access the variables outside the case

Comment: For the easy way returns the value direct from the case like case 0..2: return “small” … no need any variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pair of braces is called a ***scope***.

In Swift (unlike some other languages) there is a simple but iron rule:

- A variable declared inside a scope – in your particular case inside the `switch` statement – is visible in its own scope and on a lower level – like in your second example
- It's **not** visible on a higher level outside the scope – like in your first example.

You can even declare `size` as constant because it's guaranteed to be initialized.

```
func sizeCheckVar(value: Int) -> String {
    let size: String
    switch value {
      case 0...2: size = "small"
      case 3...5: size = "medium"
      case 6...10: size = "large"
      default: size = "huge"
    }
    return size
}
```

However actually you don't need the local variable at all. Just `return` the values immediately

```
func sizeCheckVar(value: Int) -> String {
    switch value {
      case 0...2: return "small"
      case 3...5: return "medium"
      case 6...10: return "large"
      default: return "huge"
    }
}
```

Side note: The colon in a `switch` statement is also a kind of scope separator otherwise you would get errors about redeclaration of variables in the first example.

Comment: How can I put the return value into a variable?

Comment: @submariner `let myVariable = sizeCheckVar(value: 4)`